# Chessboard and LuaLaTeX/OTF fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, font-encodings

I haven't used `chessboard` for a long time. I'm wondering how I can use it with LuaLaTeX and my own chess fonts. Can someone help me with an example file?
I'm having especially troubles how to let LuaLaTeX know about my fonts.

I've tried this:

```
\documentclass{book}%%% De Morbis Typographorum
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage[LSBC4,T1,LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessfss,chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\NeuhausenDiagram{Neuhausen-Diagram4.pfb}
\newcommand\Chessboard[1]{%
   \begin{center}
   \chessboard[setfen=#1]
   \end{center}
   \par
   \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}
\setboardfontfamily{neuhausen}
\setsidefontencoding{LY1}
\setsidefontfamily{KievitPro-TLF}
\setsidefontseries{m}
\setsidefontshape{n}
\setchessboard{%
   boardfontencoding=LSBC4,
   boardfontsize=18bp,
   %labelright=true, labeltop=true,
   labelleft=false,
   labelright,
   labelrightwidth=3.0mm, %labeltoplift=1.25mm,
   labelbottomlift=3.5mm,
   marginwidth=14.4bp, marginbottomwidth=14.4bp,
%   marginleftwidth=13bp,
   labelfontsize=8bp,
%   borderwidth=.3mm,
%   bordercolor=red,
   border=false,
   linewidth=0.25mm, padding=0mm, pgfborder,
   linewidth=0.35mm, padding=0.7mm, pgfborder,
   showmover=false,
   blackfieldmaskcolor=black!25,
   setfontcolors
}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{boardfontseries=r}
\Chessboard{bKN5/B7/pPP1R1n1/Q4p2/2k5/2p3p1/3p1R2/nr1N3B w - - 0 1}
\end{document}
```

But got an error message that LuaLaTeX cannot find the font `Neuhausen-Diagram4.pfb`

Any help appreciated!

Ulrich

Comment: Try converting your `.pfb` file to `.otf` (FontForge is one program that can do this).

Comment: That's more a problem of lualatex not being able to handle pfb directly (without tfm). If you have a tfm and the font is correctly encoded it should work like with pdflatex.

Comment: Regarding otf/ttf: the main problem is here that unicode hasn't positions for board glyphs, only figurines. So it is not quite clear, how to encode them. Btw if you want to see a special chess font https://github.com/u-fischer/lua-font-pond/blob/master/latex/latex-LSF-LSB-duckchess.pdf.

Comment: so I should stick to pdflatex and type-1 fonts, Ulrike?

Comment: yes I have both tfm, pfb, and fd files for the font. But I can't remember how to tell lualatex to use them (I put them in my local folder and updated the file name database and updmap). Probably I did something wrong here. It's just too long ago I'd used TeX :-(

Comment: o.k. I finally got it running -- copied my local Mac TeXLive to PC, and that did the trick ;-)

Comment: You should use @username if you want to notify people. Beside this: you can use type1 fonts with lualatex (the normal skak fonts works fine too) you only need to use the pdflatex *method* (with tfm and map-file).